# form looks off in ie7. css help. (screenshot incl.)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Here is the jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sPBtg/1/

In IE7, the input box for the quiz goes down a line and I can't figure out why it's doing that. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: screenshot]

What do I need to change?

Also, I noticed that in the IE7 developer tool, I get a strange empty text node. If I delete that text node, through the developer tool, everything works right again.
[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Could you share a more complete test case? If possible, a link to the actual site makes it easier to debug.

Comment: @thirtydot Sure, here is the entire Contact form: http://jsfiddle.net/sPBtg/2/ Unfortunately, the site's on maintenance mode right now and I can't take it off (by client's request) for easier debugging.

Comment: I just discovered an empty text node showing up in IE7. I updated my original post.

Comment: The bug doesn't happen in IE7 with that last link. I'm after a test case where the input is pushed down in IE7, like in your screenshot. I don't know exactly what the problem is, so I need the bug reproduced so I can try different things to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling the input box out side of the span's. You also only really need one span there to wrap the label text. Try something like:

```
<p class="quiz-wrap">
<span class="wpcf7-quiz-label">10+10=</span>
<input type="text" class="wpcf7-quiz" name="quiz">
<input type="hidden" value="996f7d842c0e718f50c0d1890f7adb57" name="_wpcf7_quiz_answer_quiz">
```

```
   .quiz-wrap {
    float: left;
    margin:0; 
   }

.wpcf7-quiz-label {
    color: #848383;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 19px;
}

.quiz-wrap input {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 30px;
}

    input {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #232323;
    border: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
   }
```

Is there a specific reason the quiz-wrap was position:relative? I didn't see any actual use for that in your sample so I removed it. You might need to check out the layout tab in the IE developer tools to see if your browser is setting a margin or other offset to the top of your input box as well.

Comment: The html is actually generated by a plugin so unfortunately I can't pull the input box outside of the spans. I checked IE's developer tools and there doesn't seem to be a margin that is being set on the input box either.